# Getting a Null value while passing data through intent to another activity

Tags: android, android-intent, null

When I do a debug, I can see the first activity sending thecorrect number, but the second activity always gets a null value. Thank you for helping.

First Activity:

```
 val intent = Intent(this@InfBateria,ControlActivity::class.java)
 intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PERCENTAGE,batteryPercentage.toString())
```

Second Activity:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.control_layout)

    m_address = intent.getStringExtra(Connect.EXTRA_ADDRESS)
    val m_percentage: String? = intent.getStringExtra(InfBateria.EXTRA_PERCENTAGE)
    textView9.text = m_percentage
```

[Edit] Code of the Activity (differente from the First one) that acttualy opens da Second Activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this,ControlActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS,address)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: in the first activity, where is the code for starting the 2nd activity?

Comment: No, that is in other activity. Is that a problem?

Comment: I mean show it as part of the question, that could be the problem. Edit the question and add that code.

Comment: Done. Hope you can help me with that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't do anything with this result intent, it will not do anything:

```
val intent = Intent(this@InfBateria,ControlActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PERCENTAGE,batteryPercentage.toString())
```

You need to update the intent that you are sending to the second activity, like so:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ControlActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS, address)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_PERCENTAGE, batteryPercentage.toString())
startActivity(intent)
```

Then your receiving activity will get both the extras. :-)

---

If you have Three activities and want to get data from 1st to 3rd you do it like this:

First Activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(ThirdActivity.EXTRA_PERCENTAGE, batteryPercentage.toString())
startActivity(intent)
```

Second Activity:

```
val intent = Intent(this, ThirdActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(ThirdActivity.EXTRA_ADDRESS, address)
// Get the data you sent to this activity and re-add it to send again
intent.putExtra(ThirdActivity.EXTRA_PERCENTAGE, getIntent().getStringExtra(ThirdActivity.EXTRA_PERCENTAGE)
startActivity(intent)
```

Third Activity:

```
m_address = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS)
m_battery = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_PERCENTAGE)
```

Comment: I need to clarify that this code:

`val intent = Intent(this,ControlActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ADDRESS,address)
startActivity(intent)`

Doensn't belong to the First Activity. It is from a differente activity.

Comment: You aren't really making sense. If your Second Activity (the one receiving the Extra's) expects 2 Extra's, then you need to send 2 Extras with any intent to that Activity.

Comment: That's what I did, I sent one extra from the First Activity (batterypercentege) and then other from the other activity (address).

Comment: No you can't do that. Like in my answer, everytime you create a new Intent you have to add the extras.

Comment: So, how can I pass the information from the First Activity to the Second? I have a variable Int batterypercentage and I want to get that value on the Second Activity. How can I do that?

Comment: added an explanation for passing through multiple activities

Comment: @tiagosilvaa8 If you found this helpful pls remember to mark it as answered https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers